# isometry on compact space

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove that an isometry $f$ on a compact metric space $X$ is necessarily bijective. I've got most of the proof,  but I can't figure out why any point in $X-f(X)$ would necessarily have to have some open neighborhood disjoint from $f(X)$.

Comment: Spoiler found by Google (first hit on searching the title of the question): http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=homework_help_2003;task=show_msg;msg=0875.0001

Comment: In other words, you want to know why the image of the compact set $X$ under the continuous map $f$ is closed in the metric space $X$?

Comment: Aha, no need to post it. The proof is standard.

Comment: @lhf Unfortunately, it just states "Take x in $X \ f(X), 0 < epsilon < dist(x,f(X))$". Why is it that $dist(x,f(X))>0$?

Comment: @yrudoy: Have you seen any theorems involving compact spaces and continuous maps, or involving compact subsets of metric (or Hausdorff) spaces?

Comment: @Jonas: Sure. But I can't think of one that would guarantee it, though I wouldn't be surprised if I was overlooking something.

Comment: @yrudoy: A compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed. i.e. the complement is open...

Comment: @yrudoy: $f$ is an isometry.  You should be able to show that it is uniformly continuous using the definition.

Comment: got it. I was using the topological definition of continuity and it isn't immediately apparent from that angle.

Comment: BTW, here is a sort of converse: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12285/isometry-in-compact-metric-spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(X)$ is compact. If $x_0\notin f(X)$, because $X$ is separated for all $x\in f(X)$ exists two disjoints open sets $U_x$ and $V_x$ such that $x_0\in U_x$ and $x\in V_x$. We can find $n\in\mathbb N$ and $x_1,\cdots,x_n\in f(X)$ such that $f(X)\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^nV_{x_j}$. Now put $U:=\bigcap_{j=1}^nU_{x_j}$.

Comment: What is the contradiction? Where do you use the isometry?

Comment: @Henno: this is an answer to the question "I can't figure out why..." (i.e. just a proof that $f(X)$ is closed).

Comment: I red too fast the problem. I tought that Henno wanted a neighborhood of $x_0$ disjoint form a neighborhood of $f(X)$.