# A problem on Isometries

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I have followed [this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340326/if-f-m-to-m-an-isometry-is-f-bijective) question and [this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120539/every-isometry-is-a-homeomorphism) one. Since a homeomorphism is automatically a bijection, shouldn't that mean it should be surjective? Am I correct in assuming that the domain is only homeomoprhic with the range, and would the result be any different if it was compact?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what definition you're using for isometry? Also: what's the actual question you're wondering about? The two related questions are quite different. So why not state, right here, the thing you're wondering about and the associated definitions?

Comment: I believe, the questions you linked use two different definitions of isometry. In the first, it is simply a distance preserving map ($d'(f(x),f(y)) = d(x,y)$), in the second, it is a bijection which preserves distances.