# Onto function on a compact metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

> $(X,d)$ is  a compact metric space  and  $$f\ :\ X\rightarrow X $$  be  such  that $$d(x,y)=d(f(x),f(y))$$
>
> Show that  $f$  is  onto .

I  have  to  show  that for  any  $y\in X$  there  exist $x\in X$  such that  $$f(x)=y.$$

How  to  begin$?$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34337/isometry-on-compact-space

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170989/a-isometric-map-in-metric-space-is-surjective

Comment: @doglah  :  How  does  that  answer  my  question $?$  Where  is  the  contradiction $?$

Comment: Sorry, my old comment had the wrong link. I hope this one is more helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189490/isometry-fx-to-x-is-onto-if-x-is-compact?lq=1