# $(M,d)$ is a compact metric space and $f:M \to M$ is bijective such that $d(f(x),f(y)) \le d(x,y) , \forall x,y \in M$ , then is $f$ an isometry?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

$(M,d)$ is a compact metric space and $f:M \to M$ is an bijective function such that $d(f(x),f(y)) \le d(x,y) , \forall x,y \in M$ , then is $f$ an isometry i.e. $d(f(x),f(y)) = d(x,y) , \forall x,y \in M$  ?

Comment: It looks like you changed the question, invalidating user10000100_u's (originally correct) answer.  I think a better solution would be to revert this to its original form and make a new question, or edit this in such a way that you're asking both questions, so that user10000100_u's answer is still ok.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12285/isometry-in-compact-metric-spaces

Answer (score 3):

I guess that $x\mapsto \frac{1}{2} x$ from $[0,1]$ into intself is injective, but is not an isometry. The answer is no.